# How to understand "with a snap in her voice like a mousetrap" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Mrs Weasley did not seem entirely satisfied with Mr Weasley's answer. As her husband leaned over to shake Harry's hand, she peered at the bandaging under his nightshirt.
>
> "Arthur," she said, **with a snap in her voice like a mousetrap**, "you've had your bandages changed. ..."
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix</sub>

I don't quite get the idea of "*with a snap in her voice like a mousetrap*" in this context. How should we understand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this definition for *snappish* (1b below) - Mrs. Weasley is using an irritated tone with Mr. Weasley, basically. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snappish

> 1a : given to curt irritable speech
>
> b : arising from annoyance or irascibility
>
> > a snappish remark

Comment: what about the part "like a mousetrap"?

Comment: A typical mousetrap has a mechanism where it snaps shut if a mouse walks into it. So Rowling is using simile here; the *snappishness* in Mrs. Weasley’s voice is like a mousetrap snapping shut. ”To snap shut” means to close abruptly and forcefully. Her speech is likewise forceful and abrupt (rude tone, not saying a lot).